# Swapping positive and negative traces of an LVDS oscillator

Tags: clock, differential

Can I swap the positive and negative traces of an LVDS oscillator (Si series of silicon labs) when connecting to clock pins of an FPGA? If no, what about adding series capacitors and using AC coupling technique?

Comment: Do you mean swap the output with the inverted output?

Comment: Note that AC coupling would remove the (typical) 1.25V DC offset of the signal. So, instead of going from, say, 0.9-1.6V, it would go from -0.35 to +0.35, and probably get squashed by protection diodes. These numbers are approximate, because LVDS is sometimes used as a general term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can swap polarity of the LVDS outputs from your clock oscillator module when connecting them to your FPGA.

So your connections would be:

```
  OSC_P  -->  FPGA_CLK_N
  OSC_N  -->  FPGA_CLK_P
```

The LVDS driver circuits for _P and _N are identical. So are the LVDS input receiver circuits for _P and _N so both signals see the same load and termination.

The FPGA's internal single-ended form of the clock will then be in 180 degrees out of phase to the external LVDS form of the clock.

You don't need to AC couple them to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the oscillator is only routed to one location, you can swap the pins.  As far as the FPGA is concerned, it receives a clock stream that is shifted half a clock cycle from what is presented externally, but that really doesn't matter.  Assuming that you are just using the oscillator as the clock source for internal logic, the FPGA just needs a stream of clock edges, it doesn't care if they are shifted. If you are monitoring FPGA activity with respect to the external clock, you will need to keep in mind that everything is shifted by half a clock.

If the clock was routed to more than one place, as long as all of them are swapped the same, then there is no issue, since all clocks will still be in phase.

I'm not sure what AC coupling has to do with clock polarity.  You can always add AC coupling, as long as the FPGA side of the AC coupled clock has something to set the common mode to the correct voltage for the FPGA input threshold.  Some FPGA inputs have input bias circuits that do this without external components.

Answer (score 0):

The LVDS uses a common current source of 3.5mA switched to either polarity output to produce 350mV into a 100 Ohm load while the other signal is switched to 0V.

Both polarities are positive switched currents which give positive switched voltages into fixed R.